# Detecting files on a remote server

Tags: powershell

Guessing remote registry isn't available (hardened builds so service isn't running) - I can't query the registry for a specific value.  However a file is present on the server I am analysing which provides the data I need.  Thus far I have written the following - I would appreciate if this can be reviewed as it just hangs - I'm guessing that I would benefit from a if exists statement for the parent directory..

Suggestions and help very much appreciated (only been using PowerShell for a short time so working hard to get to grips with this.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$servers = Get-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\list3.txt

$out = ForEach ($server in $servers)
{ 
    invoke-command -computername $server {Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Definition Updates\" -Exclude Backup -Filter mpavdlta.vdm -Recurse | Select-Object -Last 1 | Select LastWriteTime | ft -AutoSize}
} 
$out|Out-File C:\Temp\Versions.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "X:\ServerList.txt"
$logfile = "X:\Versions.log"
$Include = "Include.file"
$out = ForEach ($server in $servers)
{ 
 Write-Output(Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$Server\X$\Remote Folder\Structure\" -Exclude Backup -Filter $Include -Recurse | Select-Object -Last 1 | Select LastWriteTime | ft -AutoSize) | Out-File $logFile
} 
$out
```

Are you using account that has privileges on remote machine. If so this should provide a path to go down. This will pull server name from list and interrogate via \UNC\admin$ share. Serverlist.txt was just a list of machines in the following format.

machinename.domain.com

I had a look at your original request. Can you not loop through the serverlist and start the remote reg service, do your job and then stop it.

Something like.

```
$servers = Get-Content -Path "X:\ServerList.txt"
$Service = "Remote Registry"
$out = ForEach ($server in $servers) 
{ 
 Get-Service -Name $Service  -ComputerName $Server | Set-Service -Status Running
 Do remote reg stuff
 Get-Service -Name $Service  -ComputerName $Server | Set-Service -Status Stopped
} 
$out
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849849.aspx

Comment: Whilst I have the rights - the issue is security would probably have a fit with me doing that.  - smashing idea though and useful to know how too.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works, but it might be hanging due to your query (sounds like its capturing too many items). Does the ".vdm" file reside on that exact directory? You can remove the -Recurse if it does. Here's a modified version of yours. I just added the connection and destination checks.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$servers = Get-Content -Path C:\Windows\System32\list3.txt
$out = ForEach ($server in $servers)
{
    If(Test-Connection $server -Quiet){ 
        Invoke-Command -Computername $server {
            param([string]$parentPath)

            If(Test-Path $parentPath)
                {
                #Write-Host "$parentPath Exists on $env:COMPUTERNAME."
                Get-ChildItem -Path $parentPath -Exclude Backup -Filter mpavdlta.vdm -Recurse | Select-Object -Last 1 | Select LastWriteTime | ft -AutoSize
                }
            Else{ 
                   #Write-Host "$parentPath does not exist on $env:COMPUTERNAME" 
                }     

            } -ArgumentList $parentPath
        }
    Else { Write-host "Unable to connect to $server." }

} 
$out | Out-File C:\Temp\Versions.log
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a go, unfortunately the path doesn't remain constant - the sub section of it that does is where I was initiating the search function from.  presumably I define this with $parentPath="C:\ProgramDataMicrosoft\Microsoft Antimalware\Definition Updates\" thanks